# Boostrap Responsive columns with target

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have a table with several rows that will take more or less space depending on the screen size. 3 elements for large screens, 4 for medium screens and 2 for smaller screens.

I achieved this using the code shown below:

```
<div class=row>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 bg-danger">
      <p>MY ELEMENT</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 bg-danger">
      <p>MY ELEMENT</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 bg-danger">
      <p>MY ELEMENT</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 bg-danger">
      <p>MY ELEMENT</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

However, I need each element to target another div, that will be collapsible and that need to fill the entire column (`.col-12`). If 3 elements are on the same row, I need to have 3 divs to target and display them in the green area. But on a medium screen I need to have 4 in the green area and on small screens only 2.

I made a little sketch of what I mean :

[image: Cols example sketch]

The problem is that when I put an element under my col-* divs the other columns will shift below those elements.

```
    <div class=row>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 bg-danger" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          <p>MY ELEMENT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 collapse bg-success" id="collapseExample" >
          <p>COLAPSE ELEMENT</p>
      </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 bg-danger">
          <p>MY ELEMENT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 bg-danger">
          <p>MY ELEMENT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 bg-danger">
          <p>MY ELEMENT</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

How Can I display my green div without having the other columns go under it?

[Code snippet](https://codepen.io/Darkpingouin/pen/wvJOqwy)

Comment: Try to make a code snippet using your code. After that, someone can help.

Comment: So you want when the green column get collapsed the below red columns doesn't go up with the first column?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to try and create a JS function to execute this.
You could add and remove the elements using the Javascipt functions: [.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) or [.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) and [.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove).

There are different ways you could try to execute the solutions:

- Create an empty `<div>` and use `.append()` to add your complete `col-12 bg-success` to the element (remember to add a id to the `col` when adding it dynamically, you will need this to get it again when using `.remove()`
- The `appendChild()` method allows you to add a node to the end of the list of child nodes of a specified parent node, in your case the `bg-danger`-divs.

I hope this helps you continue. Let me know if I could help with anything when you're troubled again.

**EDIT:**

Example of first suggestion:

```html
<div class=row>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 bg-danger" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
      <p>MY ELEMENT</p>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseExample">
      {{--new col-12--}}
   </div>
  ...
</div>
```

```js
let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.addClass("col-12");
    div.addClass("bg-success");
    div.setAttribute("id", "collapseChild");
    div.innerHTML('<p>COLLAPSE ELEMENT</p>');
    document.getElementById("collapseExample").append(div);
```

Comment: Yes; but then the appened child would only be as wide as the parent (col-3) for instance, therefore it would not take the entire space I'd like it to have.

Comment: This is true, I added an example of my first suggestion, this way you can insert your `<div class="col-12 bg-success">` into an existing div **outside** the parent element.